# How to find the rank of a particular row value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with name 'points' as shown below,

```
name | point
abc    10
cde    5
efg    15
```

how to find the rank of a particular name?

For example: rank 3 for cde in the above case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way (though it requires knowing how many points a name has) is to count the rows above it

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank FROM tbl WHERE points > '%d'
```

Comment: Thank you...

Here is the final solution i got from this answer


`$sql="select count(*) as rank from points where point >(select point from points where name= 'cde') order by point desc";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['rank']+1;`

Answer (score 0):

This will be your sql query:

```
SELECT t.name FROM sometable t ORDER BY t.point DESC;
```

Once you run your query in php, you will have a sorted resultset. Then you count through that resultset until you find your name. That is your rank. Change `DESC` to `ASC` if you want the ranks to go the other direction. The contents of your function look something like this:

```
$rankingQuery = SELECT t.name FROM sometable t ORDER BY t.point DESC;
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $rank = 0;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($rankingQuery);
    $sth->execute();

    $name = $sth->fetchColumn(); 
    while ($name) {
      $rank = $rank + 1;
      if ($name == $DESIRED_NAME {
        return $rank;
      }
      $name = $sth->fetchColumn();
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```